# TableView is not populating when taking input from user, but populates when new Object is added explicitly

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, tableview, observablelist

This is the first time I'm using JavaFX and TableView. I have an application that users input golf scores to generate a handicap value for them.

I have an ArrayList that I'm using as my "database":

```
public ArrayList<Score> scoreDB = new ArrayList<>();
```

With this as the method that adds values:

```
public static Score scoreSubmit(DatePicker roundDate, TextField courseName, TextField courseRating, TextField courseSlope, TextField score)
{
    Score temp = new Score();
    //Wanted to use own Date class, must use this roundabout way to set the date correctly
    LocalDate tempDate = roundDate.getValue();

    temp.setRoundDate(tempDate.getMonthValue(), tempDate.getDayOfMonth(), tempDate.getYear());
    temp.setCourseName(courseName.getText());
    temp.setCourseRating(Double.valueOf(courseRating.getText()));
    temp.setCourseSlope(Double.valueOf(courseSlope.getText()));
    temp.setScore(Double.valueOf(score.getText()));

    return temp;
}
```

note: I used my own date class I created.

I have checked to see if the method actually works and the ArrayList does receive a value.

Here is my construction of the TableView:

```
//Table columns
    //Creating columns and setting the display to call the values from Score class
    TableColumn<Score, String> courseNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Name");
    courseNameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    courseNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseName"));

    TableColumn<Score, Date> dateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Date");
    dateColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roundDate"));

    TableColumn<Score, Double> scoreColumn = new TableColumn<>("Score");
    scoreColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    scoreColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("score"));

    //This adds rating and slope under one column
    TableColumn courseDataColumn = new TableColumn("Course Data");
    TableColumn<Score, Double> courseRatingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Rating");
    TableColumn<Score, Double> courseSlopeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Slope");
    courseDataColumn.getColumns().addAll(courseRatingColumn, courseSlopeColumn);
    courseDataColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    courseRatingColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseRating"));
    courseSlopeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseSlope"));

    scoreTable.getColumns().addAll(courseNameColumn, dateColumn, scoreColumn, courseDataColumn);

    displayLayout.setCenter(displaySP);
    displaySP.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Paint.valueOf("#006400"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
    displaySP.getChildren().add(scoreTable);
    displayLayout.setBottom(displayHbox);

    scoreTable.setItems(addScore());
```

Here are the variables from my score class:

```
private double score = 0.0;
private double courseRating = 0.0;
private double courseSlope = 0.0;
private String courseName = "";
private Date roundDate;
```

Here are my getters for score class (I have read that these must be named a certain way for it to work):

```
public double getScore()
{
    return score;
}
public String getCourseName()
{
    return courseName;
}
public Double getCourseSlope()
{
    return courseSlope;
}
public double getCourseRating()
{
    return courseRating;
}
public Date getRoundDate()
{
    return roundDate;
}
```

Here is the method for returning an observable list:

```
public ObservableList<Score> addScore()
{
    ObservableList<Score> scores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

   // scores.add(new Score());

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreDB.size(); i++)
    {
        scores.add(scoreDB.get(i));
    }

    return scores;
}
```

When only the commented out new Score() is used, the Table populates with this default score. When using the for loop, nothing is populated.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are structural problems in the code, but I guess you have logical errors too. it is not clear when you submit objects in the scoreDB because in the above code the array will be empty and logical, the cycle will do nothing.

Comment: `scoreSubmit` doesn't seem to add the `Score` object to any data structure. It's not invoked from any code snippet you posted nor do you describe how it's invoked. Is this method called at all? Is the result used or do you use the method the way the method name would suggest (i.e. you assume the method modifies some data structure)?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should pay attention to your model (the Score class). It is good (but not necessarily) working with `Properties`. The reason for this is that you will be able to edit the values ​​and the changes will automatically be reflected in the view (`TableView`). Otherwise, you will need to manually update it if you make any changes to the already added data, because `PropertyValueFactory` will generate read only property.

```
public class Score {
    private DoubleProperty score = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    private DoubleProperty courseRating = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    private DoubleProperty courseSlope = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    private StringProperty courseName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> roundDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public double getScore() {
        return score.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty scoreProperty() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(double score) {
        this.score.set(score);
    }

    public double getCourseRating() {
        return courseRating.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty courseRatingProperty() {
        return courseRating;
    }

    public void setCourseRating(double courseRating) {
        this.courseRating.set(courseRating);
    }

    public double getCourseSlope() {
        return courseSlope.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty courseSlopeProperty() {
        return courseSlope;
    }

    public void setCourseSlope(double courseSlope) {
        this.courseSlope.set(courseSlope);
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty courseNameProperty() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName.set(courseName);
    }

    public LocalDate getRoundDate() {
        return roundDate.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> roundDateProperty() {
        return roundDate;
    }

    public void setRoundDate(LocalDate roundDate) {
        this.roundDate.set(roundDate);
    }
}
```

You must also change your "database". You must use the `Observable` collection instead of a plain `List`. This will allow you to directly add data to it and they will appear automatically in the table

```
public ObservableList<Score> scoreDB = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...

//scoreTable.setItems(addScore());
scoreTable.setItems(scoreDB);

...

public void scoreSubmit() {
    Score temp = new Score();

    temp.setRoundDate(roundDate.getValue());
    temp.setCourseName(courseName.getText());
    temp.setCourseRating(Double.valueOf(courseRating.getText()));
    temp.setCourseSlope(Double.valueOf(courseSlope.getText()));
    temp.setScore(Double.valueOf(score.getText()));

    scoreDB.add(temp);
}
```

---

**Update**

This is a working example that uses almost the entire structure you have shown. Data entry is overwhelmed and you may receive `NumberFormatException` because of `Double#valueOf` calls. To avoid this problem, it is desirable to use the [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html)

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private DatePicker roundDate = new DatePicker();
    private TextField courseName = new TextField();
    private TextField courseRating = new TextField();
    private TextField courseSlope = new TextField();
    private TextField score = new TextField();
    private TableView<Score> scoreTable = new TableView<>();

    public ObservableList<Score> scoreDB = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        //Table columns
        //Creating columns and setting the display to call the values from Score class
        TableColumn<Score, String> courseNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Name");
        courseNameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        courseNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseName"));

        TableColumn<Score, LocalDate> dateColumn = new TableColumn<>("Date");
        dateColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("roundDate"));

        TableColumn<Score, Double> scoreColumn = new TableColumn<>("Score");
        scoreColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        scoreColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("score"));

        //This adds rating and slope under one column
        TableColumn courseDataColumn = new TableColumn("Course Data");
        TableColumn<Score, Double> courseRatingColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Rating");
        TableColumn<Score, Double> courseSlopeColumn = new TableColumn<>("Course Slope");
        courseDataColumn.getColumns().addAll(courseRatingColumn, courseSlopeColumn);
        courseDataColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        courseRatingColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseRating"));
        courseSlopeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("courseSlope"));

        scoreTable.getColumns().addAll(courseNameColumn, dateColumn, scoreColumn, courseDataColumn);
        scoreTable.setItems(scoreDB);

        Button addButton = new Button("Add");
        addButton.setOnAction(e -> scoreSubmit());

        HBox displayHbox = new HBox();
        displayHbox.setSpacing(5);
        displayHbox.getChildren().addAll(roundDate, courseName, courseRating, courseSlope, score, addButton);

        BorderPane displayLayout = new BorderPane();
        displayLayout.setCenter(scoreTable);
        displayLayout.setBottom(displayHbox);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(displayLayout));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void scoreSubmit() {
        Score temp = new Score();

        temp.setRoundDate(roundDate.getValue());
        temp.setCourseName(courseName.getText());
        temp.setCourseRating(Double.valueOf(courseRating.getText()));
        temp.setCourseSlope(Double.valueOf(courseSlope.getText()));
        temp.setScore(Double.valueOf(score.getText()));

        scoreDB.add(temp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have created a new ScoreProperty class and am now using that class for my table. Still no luck, the only way I've gotten input from the user is by also having a score object specifically created as well.

Comment: @DrSooch You're doing something wrong, but what exactly can not be said because you do not show code. Take a look at the recipe of my post above. I have added a rough (but working) example of adding data to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what I did, but I seemed to have fixed it. Here's my scoreSubmit() method implementation:

```
 //Submit Button for score scene, implements method for setting Score Class variables
    Button scoreSubmit = GHINAppMethods.submitButton();
    scoreSubmit.defaultButtonProperty().bind(nameInput.focusedProperty());
    scoreSubmit.setOnAction(e ->
    {
        //checks to make sure values are correct
        switch (GHINAppMethods.checkScoreValues(courseRating, courseSlope, score))
        {
            //all values valid
            case 0:
            {
                //adds score to a "database" that will eventually be used in ScoreHistory class
                scoreDB.add(GHINAppMethods.scoreSubmit(roundDateTest, courseName, courseRating, courseSlope, score));
               //ScoreIterator has no use at this point
                System.out.println(scoreDB.get(scoreIterator));
                scoreIterator++;
                System.out.println(scoreIterator);
                System.out.println(scoreDB.size());
                GHINAppMethods.addAnotherScore(scoreTextFields, clearAll, displayScene, entryWindow, scoreTable, scores);
                break;
            }
            //rating invalid
            case 1:
            {
                courseRating.clear();
                GHINAppMethods.ratingInvalid();
                break;
            }
            //slope invalid
            case 2:
            {
                courseSlope.clear();
                GHINAppMethods.slopeInvalid();
                break;
            }
            //score invalid
            case 3:
            {
                score.clear();
                GHINAppMethods.scoreInvalid();
                break;
            }
            //Fatal System Error (shouldn't be used)
            default:
            {
                GHINAppMethods.fatalError();
                System.out.println("fatal error");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

The checkScoreValues() method just checks to make sure the values are correct (I am still missing out on exceptions but it helps). checkScoreValues returns an int, and the switch statement will execute. scoreDB.add(...) and addAnotherScore(), are the only methods that are actually used. The others are for error checking.